# Using double quotes inside string in dart result in unwanted outcome

Tags: string, flutter, android-studio, dart

FLUTTER AND IDE INFO (Please let me know, if you have further info)
By the way, I am using Android Studio 4.2.2 (June 24, 2021 version) despite what Flutter doctor says.

```
C:\Users\Administrator>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1052], locale tr-TR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.4)
[!] Android Studio
    X android-studio-dir = C:\ProgramFiles\Android\Android Studio
    X Android Studio not found at C:\ProgramFiles\Android\Android Studio
[√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

Dart SDK version: 2.13.4 (stable) (Wed Jun 23 13:08:41 2021 +0200) on "windows_x64"
```

What I am trying to is, I am creating a string for using it as argument inside the [Process.Run](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-io/Process/run.html).
I am using the command line for firing the [FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/)(Fastest copy tool in windows and have a really good queue process). I need to use double quote without breaking the code because without opening and closing with double quotes("), FastCopy will not work where Folder name has space in it

Here is sample:

```
String path : r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sample.txt"
String output: r"C:\"

// This will not cause any problems because folder names have no space
// This has no double quote
Process.run("cmd",
           ['/c start /wait C:\\Users\\Administrator\\FastCopy\\FastCopy.exe /cmd=force_copy /auto_close /estimate=TRUE $path /to=$output'],
           runInShell: true,);
```

And now when I put double quote(") before and after the variables:

```
String path : r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sample.txt"
String output: r"C:\"

// This has double quote in it
Process.run("cmd",
           ['/c start /wait C:\\Users\\Administrator\\FastCopy\\FastCopy.exe /cmd=force_copy /auto_close /estimate=TRUE "$path" /to="$output"'],
           runInShell: true,);
```

If I output the arguments part as string, The result is expected output string. Console shows what  it should be. And when I run it myself from cmd console it work as expected. But when I run it inside the flutter it adds another "C:" before the string so it becomes

```
C:\C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\profanity_TR.txt
```

And it throws Directory error. Error comes from FastCopy.exe that I have linked.

Currently, I am using quoteless version and has no error. But I really want to solve the problem because using it with directory that has space in name and don't want to encounter this type of problem.

Comment: To clarify, do you need to use the double quotes as a char inside the String?
Can't you solve it by put '\' before the double quote?

Comment: @L.Gangemi Thanks for answering but nothing changes with putting that symbol, \ just escape the character where I use '(single quote), I don't need to use \(escape char). Regardless I tried, and it is same.

Comment: Can you use `Process.run('cmd', '/c', 'start', '/wait', 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\FastCopy\\FastCopy.exe', '/cmd=force_copy', '/auto_close', '/estimate=TRUE', path, '/to=$output'], runInShell: true)` instead?  That is, pass a  list of argument strings instead of a single string, and let `Process.run` quote things as necessary for you.

Comment: Also, your example path (`"r"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\sample.txt"`) doesn't match your output (`"C:\C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\profanity_TR.txt"`).  Which is it?  And exactly where do you observe the latter string?  Have you verified that `Process.run` is being invoked with the expected string after string interpolation occurs?

Comment: @jamesdlin Sorry I just change the sample file but yes output is the same. As I said in my question, I observerd excess "C:\" in FastCopy itself.

Comment: @jamesdlin For your first question, I also tried to pass arguments part part in a list and still same result.

Comment: Can you also try `Process.run("start", [...], runInShell: true)`?  I don't think you need `cmd /c` with `runInShell: true`.

Comment: @jamesdlin Without /c or /k key. And as a note, I did the same thing in C# Winforms. and Python Same commands but problem only occured in Dart. Regardless, as tested this has nothing to do with my problem. Thanks for trying again.